# How to evaluate an updateable classifier in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I'm using the Weka API to implement an incremental classifier following the steps in http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+Weka+in+your+Java+code

However, I do not find any option to evaluate the classifier (using a test set) since the only documentation is using small datasets (which I don't have, that's why I'm using an updateable classifier). Are there any updateable evaluation available? Or the only way is doing it manually?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any classifier in WEKA can be tested using a `Evaluation` object like so:

```
Evaluation eTest = new Evaluation(testInstances);
eTest.evaluateModel(yourUpdatableModelHere, testInstances);
//Print the results
System.out.println(eTest.toSummaryString());
//Get the confusion matrix
double[][] confMatrix = eTest.confusionMatrix();
```

For more, see the JavaDoc on `Evaluation` [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html#evaluateModel(weka.classifiers.Classifier,%20weka.core.Instances,%20java.lang.Object...)).